# How to fix Angular-translate FOUC issue using translation-cloak?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-translate

I've problem with flickering of texts during first loading.

I tried all solutions I've found on internet but none of them worked...

My version of angular-translate is newest 2.4.2.

Here is example HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testapp">
<head>
    <title translate-cloak>{{ 'page.appName' | translate }}</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="static/favicon.ico"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div>
                <a href="/"><strong translate-cloak>{{ 'page.appName' | translate }}</strong></a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div ng-view></div>
<script src="javascripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/angular-translate.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/angular-translate-loader-url.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/angular-translate-storage-local.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is JavaScript:

```
angular.module('testapp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngCookies', 'ngTable', 'mgcrea.ngStrap', 'pascalprecht.translate'])
        .config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', '$translateProvider',
            function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider, $httpProvider, $translateProvider) {
                $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
                $routeProvider.when('/', {
                    templateUrl: 'views/main.html'
                }).otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escaped').useLocalStorage().useStaticFilesLoader({
                    prefix: 'static/languages/',
                    suffix: '.json'
                }).use('en-EN');
            }
        ]);
```

Answer (score 5):

You need provide a translation inside your $translateProvider configuration and define it as the preferred language.

[The documentation call this FOUC](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/12_asynchronous-loading#asynchronous-loading_fouc---flash-of-untranslated-content) (Flash Of Untranslated Content).

I experimented too that when I put a value in translate-cloak, like `translate-cloak="any"`, the `.translate-cloak` class is added to the tag, but when I put only `translate-cloak` the `.translate-cloak` isn't added.

Remember that you need style the `.translate-cloak` class.